# Left outer join with 2 column missing some output rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image: View Design]

When I select all rows from table zvw_test it return 145 rows.
Table Customer_Class_Price have 160 rows.
When I try to join this 2 table with 2 condition it return 122 rows.
I don't understand why it not return all rows from zvw_test (145 rows) 
becasue I use left outer join it should return all rows from left table.

Thank you.

```
 SELECT zvw_test.Goods_ID, 
        zvw_test.Thai_Name, 
        zvw_test.UM, 
        zvw_test.CBal, 
        Customer_Class_Price.ListPrice
   FROM zvw_test 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Customer_Class_Price ON zvw_test.Goods_ID = Customer_Class_Price.Goods_ID AND 
                                zvw_test.UM = Customer_Class_Price.UM
  WHERE (Customer_Class_Price.ClassCode = '444-666')
```

Comment: is it because of the `WHERE     (Customer_Class_Price.ClassCode = '444-666')`?  you should change it to `WHERE     (Customer_Class_Price.ClassCode IS NULL OR Customer_Class_Price.ClassCode = '444-666')`

Comment: After I change where clause it reture 138 rows.
Still missing 7 rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN query not returning expected rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861927/left-outer-join-query-not-returning-expected-rows)

Comment: There must be 7 rows that join to a ClassCode that is neither '444-666' nor is it NULL.

Comment: which is why you should move the where condition to the join clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem before, I used a CTE to solve this, like:

```
WITH A AS
(
    SELECT Customer_Class_Price.Goods_ID, Customer_Class_Price.UM, Customer_Class_Price.ListPrice  
    FROM Customer_Class_Price
    WHERE Customer_Class_Price.ClassCode = '444-666'
)
SELECT zvw_test.Goods_ID, zvw_test.Thai_Name, zvw_test.UM, zvw_test.CBal, A.ListPrice
FROM zvw_test LEFT OUTER JOIN A 
ON zvw_test.Goods_ID = A.Goods_ID AND zvw_test.UM = A.UM
```

Comment: This query is working
But I don't understand why use CTE can solve this problem.
Can you explain.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

By putting one of your columns from the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` table in your `WHERE` clause, you have effectively turned it into an `INNER JOIN`. You need to move that up to the `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You demand in your WHERE clause:

```
 (Customer_Class_Price.ClassCode = '444-666')
```

Ergo you are not selecting rows where `Customer_Class_Price.ClassCode IS NULL`. `Customer_Class_Price.ClassCode` would be NULL if there is no corresponding row, but you are filtering those out explicitely.