# How can I filter out coordinates (lat, lon) in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, coordinates, latitude-longitude

#### TL;DR

[This image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861927/left-outer-join-query-not-returning-expected-rows) of a left outer join depicts exactly what I would like: removing rows of a `data.table` based on two columns `lat, lon` that *exactly* match the `lat, lon` columns of another `data.table`.

#### The Problem

Suppose I have the following `data.table` `"dt.master"` with over 1 million of rows containing an `id` and coordinates of a certain location `lat, lon`:

```
id    lat      lon
1     43.23    5.43
2     43.56    4.12
3     52.14   -9.85
4     43.56    4.12
5     43.83    9.43
...   ...      ...
```

What I would like to do is remove the rows that match a certain pair of coordinates. You could think of that pair of coordinates as being put on the following blacklist (again a `data.table` named `"dt.blacklist"`):

```
lat      lon
43.56    4.12
11.14   -5.85
```

In this case, when applying the blacklist, the answer would have to be:

```
id    lat      lon
1     43.23    5.43
3     52.14   -9.85
5     43.83    9.43
...   ...      ...
```

As straightforward as it seems, I cannot get it right.

#### What I did so far

- Using `merge`, like such:

  ```
  dt.result <- merge(dt.master, dt.blacklist[, c("lat", "lon")], by.x=c("lat", "lon"), by.y=c("lat", "lon"))
  ```

  But that yields the rows that match and is thus an inner join. I thought about removing rows based on this result by using `subset`:

  ```
  subset(dt.master, lat != dt.result$lat & lon != dt.result$lon)
  ```

  But the issue is that it partially works as then only 1 row in the above example is removed and not 2 rows as I would like. Somehow it only removes the first "hit".
- Using a quick and dirty solution by concatenating `lat, lon` to a new column named `"C"` in both data tables and then removing it as such:

  ```
  dt.master[C != dt.blacklist$C]
  ```

  Yet, the same issue arises where only 1 of the two rows is removed.

Comment: As these are floats, could you check if the numbers match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
dt.master[!dt.blacklist, on = .(lat,lon)]
```

The output:

```
   id   lat   lon
1:  1 43.23  5.43
2:  3 52.14 -9.85
3:  5 43.83  9.43
```

Thanks to the warning of the green wise guy, that joinng on floating points could have unintended side-effects. By converting to integers you could prevent that. The join will as a result look a bit more complicated:

```
dt.master[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD,function(x) as.integer(x*100)), .SDcols = 2:3
          ][!dt.blacklist[, (1:2) := lapply(.SD,function(x) as.integer(x*100))], on = .(lat,lon)
            ][, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, `/`, 100), .SDcols = 2:3][]
```

The output is the same:

```
   id   lat   lon
1:  1 43.23  5.43
2:  3 52.14 -9.85
3:  5 43.83  9.43
```

Comment: Known as an anti-join

Comment: I'd be really cautious in doing a join on floating point numbers... maybe it would be better converting those coordinates to integers (e.g. 43.23  --> 4323) and then join them...

Comment: @digEmAll thank you very much, updated the answer to incorporate that issue

Comment: Great, this works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `fsetdiff` from `data.table`

```
fsetdiff(df1[,-1], df2)
```

---

or can use `anti_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1, df2)
#  id   lat   lon
#1  1 43.23  5.43
#2  3 52.14 -9.85
#3  5 43.83  9.43
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution!